# dxtreme multichannelapplication with Breeze js

Tags: devexpress, breeze

I have a running multichannelapplication connceted via wcf service to a sqlserver 2012. When I stopp the service the app keep running and the data is stored in the entity manager  of breeze:

```
(function () {

var oldClient = OData.defaultHttpClient;

var myClient = {
    request: function (request, success, error) {
        if (request.requestUri.indexOf("$metadata", request.requestUri.length - "$metadata".length) !== -1) {
            request.headers.Accept = "application/xml";
        }

        return oldClient.request(request, success, error);
    }
};

OData.defaultHttpClient = myClient;

breeze.config.initializeAdapterInstance("dataService", "OData", false);

var dataNS = DevExpress.data;
var manager = new breeze.EntityManager({
    dataService: new breeze.DataService({
        serviceName: "http://localhost:57049/DataService.svc",
        hasServerMetadata: false,
        adapterName: "OData"
    })
});




App.db = {
    tblInvoice: new dataNS.BreezeStore({
        entityManager: manager,
        resourceName: "tblInvoice",
        autoCommit: true,
    }),
```

when i restart the service the data should be synchronized but it doesn't do this automaticly. The [Breeze api](http://www.breezejs.com/sites/all/apidocs/classes/EntityManager.html#method_saveChanges) says `saveChanges()` to save to entity manager. How to sync the entities with the server if the service is available again?